# data connector power query visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, powerbi, powerquery

i am trying to use visual studio and i have installed the power query extension inside visual studio and i was presented with this piece of code:

```
> let
>     result = cntrra20_nfssql.Contents() in
>     result
```

From there I have no idea how to proceed as this is all new to me. How should I continue? I am not even sure what programming language this is. I am currently creating live PowerBI dashboards reading from multiple sources and the online dashboards is having difficulty some of the servers except the ones being managed by me. I will use this Data Connector in my gateway.

Comment: That is the M language that queries are built in Power Query. Do you need to create a custom data connection to read from your data sources? As far as I know that is the primary purpose of the PQ SDK. Normally you use Power Query in PowerBI Desktop to setup your data connections, and you can save/upload a dashboard out of that.

Comment: Thats exacly what i need to do